# Allow sound file uploads in questions and answers?

Tags: feature-request, audio

Should Stack Exchange introduce the ability to upload embedded sounds (maybe via HTML5/Flash, whichever the user has) as part of questions and answers to Stack Exchange?  It could require a certain amount of rep to stop new users from doing it frivolously.

My rationale behind this is the new language & usage sites.  I often find myself thinking that it might be helpful, when discussing a regional dialect or something, for the person answering to just *pronounce* what they're trying to describe in words.

Comment: Sure, as long as this is limited to those few sites were it might be helpful.  I'd hate to see this on SO, for example.

Comment: @Brock Why would you hate it? Can you give an example? It's not like there are *that* many use cases on SO, but you don't have to click it or anything. It would for example absolutely make sense on SU ("My laptop fan sounds like this...").

Comment: @slhck: My laptop fan sounds like this: Never gonna give you up, never gonna let you down...

Comment: Related: [embedded audio player on language sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152282/273494)

Answer (score 7):

For the most part, this is already possible: [Embedded audio player](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/embedded-audio-player/176#176) (although you don't have an upload path directly through us).

This is only enabled on those sites were this seems to be useful, and your argument isn't bad, so we may consider it if the need is indeed there. Do you have any particular examples?

Comment: A discussion on how to pronounce 'Pope' in French here: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/515/quelle-est-la-prononciation-correcte-de-pape

Comment: Would it be possible to implement some sort of upload mechanism [like you have with imgur for images](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/), so that it is not needed to register/login at SoundCloud to upload manually first?

Comment: In a related question; on the language SE, there appears to be a valid case for the ability of users to simply click a site widget and be able to record a sound that becomes part of the conversation on language. I've asked this question on Chinese SE (http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/370/feature-request-audio-snippets-similar-to-image-uploads). Should that question be migrated to META.se?

Answer (score 2):

There technically is a way to do this without relying on third party sites, using a code snippet that can be run, at least on SE sites that allow runnable code snippets.

You just need to convert the file to base64 and use HTML5. E.g.

```html
<audio autoplay controls src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,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">
  The “audio” tag does not appear to be supported by your browser.
</audio>
```

Comment: As someone noted in a comment when I suggested this in another Q though, it's not necessarily great to get people accustomed to running code on SE that they may not understand, though...