# Add support for sound samples on posts

Tags: feature-request, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow sound file uploads in questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103850/allow-sound-file-uploads-in-questions-and-answers)

On the new [linguistics site](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-difference-between-voiced-and-voiceless-stop-consonants/52#52) (private beta members only at the time of this writing), there are already a some of questions about phonology. I anticipate that it will continue to be that way, and we will soon be in need of having support for sound samples.

Phonology is hard to describe in words (without technical linguistic jargon like *unaspirated voiced labiodental nasalized affricate*), so having sound samples is immensely helpful. We are able to link to sound samples, but in my experience, sound links often rot quickly, and it is a pain to follow a link and download a sound sample that is only two seconds long.

If bandwidth is an issue, you could restrict the length to 10 seconds or so, since most recordings to demonstrate phonology are very short.

Comment: For now, I'd suggest linking to http://vocaroo.com/