# Embedded audio player on language sites

Tags: feature-request, languages, audio

[Allowing audio files with pronunciaton](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236/allowing-audio-files-with-pronunciaton) asks the ability to embed audio of pronunciations. While the question was specifically asked for the Russian site, I'm sure such functionality would be useful on all the language sites.

[Can an embedded audio player be added to Audio.SE and Music.SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72365/can-an-embedded-audio-player-be-added-to-audio-se-and-music-se) was asked in 2010, requesting an embedded audio player functionality be added to audio.SE and music.SE. That question has been tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), which means the functionality already exists within the SE.

Would it be possible to extend this functionality to language sites and, specifically, russian.SE?

Comment: I guess I'm the only one who sees the irony between this feature request and [Stack Overflow is not trying to start audio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332229/stack-overflow-is-not-trying-to-start-audio)

Answer (score 28):

The ability to upload audio clips  has been requested on English Language Learners ([Embed an audio player](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/299/)), English Language & Usage ([Why can't we add video (or even audio) clips to posts?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13375/80039)) and on Japanese Language ([Allow audio uploads](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1513)).

Short audio clips would be very helpful with pronunciation questions and answers. Many people, while familiar with the International Phonetic Alphabet, can't easily translate from those symbols (ˌɪntə(ː)ˈnæʃənl fəʊˈnɛtɪk ˈælfəbɪt) into sounds or translate something they've heard into IPA.

On English Language & Usage, a question asking for identification of a dialect in a YouTube clip was criticized for forcing readers to go off-site to understand the question. If we had the ability to upload sound clips, the question could possibly have been salvaged.

Another issue with forcing people off-site for audio clips (mentioned in the Japanese Language meta question) is link rot. There's no way to extract the relevant bits of an audio clip and include it in the question or answer. [The Help Center explains](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer):

> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link**, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Is there some concern about adding support for [SoundCloud-hosted audio](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/a/176) on language sites that wasn't an issue for the sites where it was enabled? I think for language sites, the clip length could be very limited if storage is the issue.

Here is an example on ELL where this feature would have been useful. The question was very well-received, but who knows if 10 years from now that link will still be active?

[How can I get rid of my Indian accent and sound more neutral/native](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/245199/9161)

Comment: I want to upvote twice! I can't :(

Answer (score 10):

There technically is a way to do this, using a code snippet that can be run, at least on SE sites that allow runnable code snippets.

You just need to convert the file to base64 and use HTML5. E.g.

```html
<audio autoplay controls src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,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">
  The “audio” tag does not appear to be supported by your browser.
</audio>
```

Comment: Wow! I wouldn't even think of this!

Comment: great solution ! Note that you can add video (without audio) directly in the markdown as gif image.

Comment: @aloisdg Thanks. Yeah, I've [previously encoding video to GIF for an SE answer, as well](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/208823/flying-bloodthirsty-lampshades/208831#208831). The data URL method could be applied to embed small/short/highly compressed videos in HTML5 `<video...` elements as well, but the questioner here was asking about just audio, so I limited myself above to just addressing the audio case.