# Advertisements dark mode

Tags: feature-request, advertising, dark-mode

The blocks with advertisements on the right side should have dark colors in dark mode, the advertisement is a spotlight with a white background.

Comment: Easy to solve https://ublockorigin.com/ (you really should not use this site without an adblock, see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332229/stack-overflow-is-not-trying-to-start-audio)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, yes, but it is a sugestion to improve the advertising, it forces me to use an ad blocker, thanks a lot for the tip, I didn't know ublockorigin.