# Does Stack Exchange collect immutable data?

Tags: discussion, privacy, terms-of-service, user-information

I want to use Stack Exchange but I am unsure what data is collected. The data I am most worried about is data that cannot change, like my race, device id's, or legal identity.

Does SE collect data about me or my device that cannot be changed?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy

Comment: @Glorfindel an example: We collect information **such as** your username, password, email address, IP address (collected at each site visit). It doesn't explain it throughly.

Comment: So I am unsure of the _extent_ of the data collected.

Comment: You are asking it the wrong way. What you should be asking is "Does Stack Exchange collect [name of whatever you're afraid of here]?".

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I altered the format of the question. I was worried about data that cannot change, or that cannot reasonably change in a reasonable amount of time. Like my race, legal identity, etc. Even device id's like hardware signatures because those cannot really be changed reasonably (short of getting a new device).

Comment: Better now, and let's hope staff will see this and reply. (Can take a while)

Comment: How do you suppose Stack Exchange would collect data on your race?

Comment: @F1Krazy analytics and if I use a Google account

Comment: @F1Krazy annual survey, for one.

Comment: What site or service forced you to enter your so-called "race"?

Comment: _ehem_ https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332229/384528

Answer (score 2):

> "The data I am most worried about is data that cannot change, like my race, device id's, or legal identity. Does SE collect data about me or my device that cannot be changed?".

1. You are not asked for your race, except for anonymized surveys.
2. Your *device ID* is collected in the server logs, most employees don't look at it; and those who could would only do so to diagnose a bug.
3. You don't have to give your real name or use the same email as you usually use on the Internet. Remember that it **is** prohibited to use multiple emails and identities to interact with each other and, for example, to upvote each other.
4. All of the above information ***can*** be changed, perhaps not easily, but you could change it within a few minutes. A record is kept of such changes, so the ability to change the information is entirely separate from the usefulness of doing so.

The answer, thus far, is "no"; but wait, there's more.

While you could change the above information, for all that's worth, and you are free to delete your account at any time (converting all your questions and answers to an anonymous user name) you are not allowed to delete your questions and answers en masse.

The [terms of service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) make all your contributions subject to [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), they are the property of Stack Exchange; subject to that licensing agreement.

Even ***if*** you deleted everything, it could be restored.

As long as you keep your personal information private, and don't leak anything about yourself in your profile and questions or answers, then no information about you is collected.

It's the same anywhere, whatever you give out is difficult to get back; you need to take steps to protect your privacy in the first place, rather than giving it up and trying to get it back.