# Should the Misleading Information Policy apply to Meta posts?

Tags: discussion, meta, per-site-meta, code-of-conduct

A brand-new [Misleading Information Policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct/misleading-information) has just been released that encourages users to flag, and for moderators to delete, posts that they feel are false in a dangerous way. Many of the examples given for the use of the policy relate to political misinformation such as [QAnon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QAnon) and scientific misinformation such as [anti-vax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccine_hesitancy) rhetoric.

One thing I was wondering about was whether the policy applies or should apply to posts on Meta (either Mother Meta or per-site Metas) that are thought to contain false information about the company, the sites, the community, or the moderation team. **Should it?**

**Discussion:**

Recall the [Monica matter in 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334399/summing-up-the-main-issues-the-story-so-far). While I am disappointed that the company did not acknowledge the set of facts that I believe are most in keeping with the evidence, I will acknowledge (give credit where credit is due) that the company refrained from administratively deleting pro-Monica content.

With the new policy, I wonder how 2019 would have been different. Regardless of which set of facts (Monica's or the Company's) were true in the end, expressing the other viewpoint could have been seen as violating up to three clauses of the new policy:

> - Is likely to significantly contribute to the risk of physical or psychological harm to a person or a group of people
> - Promotes the specific views of a party, government, or ideology by using false claims regarding others
> - ...
> - Misrepresents, denies, or makes unsubstantiated claims about historical or newsworthy events or the people involved in them

If Monica didn't violate the Code of Conduct (CoC), then alleging that she did clearly has the potential to cause psychological harm to not only her but her supporters. Likewise, if she did, in fact, violate it, then her claiming that she didn't belittles and risks psychologically harming the brave souls who reported her violations and called her out on them.

Since moderators on the network are democratically elected, misinformation about individual moderators might also violate the clause:

> - Is likely to significantly harm democratic institutions or voting processes or to cause voter or census suppression

One thing that some might say is that those on each side of the Monica matter believed in the truth of what they were posting, and that whichever side was "wrong" in the end were not liars, but honestly mistaken. My problem with that assertion is that nowhere in the policy is knowledge of the falsity of the information (in legal parlance, *scienter*) made an element of violating the policy, and, in any event, a large number of people who post the kind of political and scientific misinformation mentioned above (e.g. QAnon and anti-vax) are either true believers in such content or don't know any better. They are not liars, but misinformed themselves and (arguably) deserve to be educated out of their ignorance rather than punished.

For a non-Monica example, I have been considering flagging the MSE post [Stack Overflow is not trying to start audio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332229/336163) for moderator removal as misinformation, as the reaction makes it clear that the consensus of the community was that the information posted by Juan M was demonstrably false. I have refrained from raising the flag, however, as I am afraid that I will get a stern flag decline message that facts that have already been determined true by the Company are above the policy.

Comment: Anyone else running out of popcorn at this point?

Comment: I've been wondering about these too, particularly given that the statements in the recent [AI generated content policy post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389583/271271) are definitely misleading and are "likely to significantly harm democratic institutions or voting processes". Note that what they explicitly state in that post is only about *their own perceptions*, so the actual statements can't be falsified.

Comment: However, those statements do lead people to substantially different conclusions and extrapolations about what's happening on the network and moderator actions which are "normal" from what is being said, but which are wholly incompatible with the fact that **SE has, as of this time, identified *absolutely ZERO* suspensions or deletions for AI generated content as being inappropriate or wrong and reversed none** (both publicly and privately).

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying there are aren't any deletions or suspension which are wrong. We *do* make mistakes. SO mods *can* identify a *few* where we have reviewed the action at the user's request or instigation of another moderator and reversed the suspension and/or deletion. But the *real* question is what is the relative harm between a few inaccurate actions that get reversed (or whatever level it actually is) and the harm to the sites, the network, and company by having large quantities of AI generated content masquerading as user contributed. *That* needs investigation/determination.

Comment: @Makyen but simply asserting that something is only a perception does not make it not misinformation. If I make posts saying "It is my perception that Biden stole the election" and "It is my perception that Covid doesn't exist and that the so-called vaccines are being used to microchip citizens", should my "perception" caveats be enough to save my posts? I would think not. Call a spade a spade. Calling a spade a club doesn't make it a club.

Comment: I'm not sure this should be a discussion question, or a support one. I think this is one of those things staff should probably clarify (so a support thing) instead of a discussion between users where the most popular answer 'wins'. I doubt users can set a policy that goes against staff interpretation of the CoC anyways. Any particular reason you chose discussion over support as a tag?

Comment: Just from a birds eye perspective: any Code of Conduct should probably apply to all public parts of a website equally.

Comment: *"Misrepresents, denies, or makes unsubstantiated claims about historical or newsworthy events or the people involved in them"* ─ I wonder if this includes, for example, posting a public policy announcement about Stack Exchange which misrepresents the actual policy as communicated to the moderators who have to enforce it. The policy is probably newsworthy, given that the original ban on ChatGPT was reported by The Verge, The Register and other tech news sites.

Comment: Even in the remote case Monica had violated any policy (maybe something posted while she was quite conveniently offline for a religious-related reason) I would expect that a company would just *silently* remove her. Instead someone (like the best of fisherman singing their great battle against "Ye Kraken of the Seven Seas") immediately went to an online news outlet to spread the word. I may be evil, but this look like they just wanted a scapegoat that could be publicly executed to show how they care for  LGBTQIA+ and how the new policy was already working....